# Programmatically reset opengl

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, processing

Im using a library that uses Opengl(Processing). Im experiencing strange issues regarding the graphics matrix depth on different runs:

If a run starts correctly then the application never crashes, else i get an error regarding matrix depth(too many pop or push) in random points and then many subsequent runs are bound to fail.

I checked and my push and pops are correctly paired and i get errors like too many pop even right after i have done a push:

push

...

1 line code

...

pop (too many pop error)

Is there some way to programmatically reset the state of opengl or anyways to manage the matrix depth issue?

Comment: that looks like a different problem masked as unbalanced matrix stack use. So first some follow up questions for you (to help locate the problem): . Are you using multi-threading?  do you have more then one GL context. what OS and gfx card are you using? Do you have any memory or resource leaks in your App (AMD drivers are very susceptible to things like that)? What is the biggest depth of your push per single matrix ? Also it is a good idea to try GL debuger like GLIntercept to check GL calls

Comment: Make sure you push/pop the *same* matrix stack. In legacy OpenGL there are at least 4 matrix stacks: projection, modelview, texture and color (switched with glMatrixMode), and you have to balance pushs/pops within each stack.

Comment: I am using all the (processing)opengl functions in the same graphical thread, but i also have some awt components so yes. im using a ge-force 580, AMD fx 6 cores. im using at most 3-4 level of nested transformation matrixs. i never used gl debugger, nor opengl directly, i was using processing because it puts a layer on graphical functions that i dont know in detail. The push/pop should be balanced, the processing matrix should be an abstraction (i think) so i dont get to know exactly what low level operation im doing.

Answer (score 0):

Processing has a `resetMatrix()` that you could use. More info is available in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/resetMatrix_.html).

But what you're describing sounds pretty suspicious, so you should probably try to figure out why you're seeing the error instead of just working around them. Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: the reset matrix resets the current matrix to the normal one (1,1,1,1 diag) the matrix stack its used to do nested transformations, like the translation of a rotated object ecc... i dont know if i can do a MCVE on this, the problem itself its the lack of robustness of the application when it grows. i was interested in some way if any to level the opengl state.

Comment: @Yggdrasil Like has been pointed out, this sounds like a bug in your code, specifically that you're pushing and popping matrixes out of balance.